# Custom coding standard ruleset not working for Code Sniffer in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, phpcodesniffer, psr-2

I have a project in **PhpStorm 2019.2.3** for which I want to use a custom coding standard ruleset with PHP Code Sniffer. The Code Sniffer works as expected, w**hen I choose a provided coding standard**, but **when I change to my custom ruleset, all sniffs disappear**.

I copied the whole /PSR2 folder under `/PHP_CodeSniffer-3.4.2/src/Standards/`, named it `PSR2-Custom` and edited the contained `ruleset.xml` to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="PSR2R">
    <rule ref="PSR2">
    <exclude name="Squiz.Functions.MultiLineFunctionDeclaration.BraceOnSameLine" />
        <exclude name="PSR2.Classes.ClassDeclaration.OpenBraceNewLine" />
    </rule>
    <rule ref="Generic.Functions.OpeningFunctionBraceKernighanRitchie" />
</ruleset>
```

What I think it does is that it uses the PSR2 coding standard and excludes two of the contained rules, inspired by [phpcs: How can I modify PSR2 to check that the brace is on the same line as the method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585906/phpcs-how-can-i-modify-psr2-to-check-that-the-brace-is-on-the-same-line-as-the) and https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues/703

These are my settings:

A) Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Quality Tools:

local configuration with path to phpcs.bat (PHP_CodeSniffer-3.4.2, manually downloaded) (as [documented](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-php-code-sniffer.html#installing-configuring-code-sniffer))

B) Settings > Editor > Inspections: PHP > Quality tools > PHP Code Sniffer Validation:

-> choosing PSR2 in 'Coding standards' dropdown: sniffs marked
-> choosing PSR2-Custom  in 'Coding standards' dropdown: no sniffs marked anymore

I checked similar issues on SO, but non of them helped me with my problem, e.g.
[Custom PMD ruleset not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40299075/custom-pmd-ruleset-not-working)

I can't figure out, where I went wrong. Is my ruleset config buggy? Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Oh, yes, I have other sniffs in the PHP code (other than the excluded) that should be detected.

Comment: What PhpStorm version are you using?

Comment: @Ástþór Damn I forgot that, I updated the question text, thanks.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply: please update to 2019.3.4 and check how it goes.